# Does it matter where to place parallel() call in the stream pipeline?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

For instance, `parallel()` before `filter()`

```
Stream.of(...)
      .parallel()
      .filter(...)
      .forEach(...);
```

and `parallel()` after `filter()`

```
Stream.of(...)
      .filter(...)
      .parallel()
      .forEach(...);
```

Does order of calling `parallel()` affect the stream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not matter where you place `parallel()`. A stream is not evaluated until a terminal operation (in your case `forEach`) is called.

From the Javadoc:

> Returns an equivalent stream that is parallel. May return itself, either because the stream was already parallel, or because the underlying stream state was modified to be parallel.
> This is an intermediate operation.

The only situation in which the order matters is if you're also calling `sequential`, in which case the following applies:

> The most recent sequential or parallel mode setting applies to the execution of the entire stream pipeline.

For more information see [the relevant Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)